# apt-get does not proceed with package installation if one package is held

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, apt, software-installation, held-packages

I have put a hold on one of the packages via `apt-mark hold cmake` but when installing some dependencies for some software, the software's automatic package update script is trying to update lots of packages via `apt-get install package1 package2 cmake etc`. This causes my build script to halt and the software's package update script throws following error:

> E: Held packages were changed and -y was used without
>   --allow-change-held-packages. ERROR! apt-get failed to install requested packages, exiting.

I wonder, how can I hold a package and at the same time make `apt-get` somehow ignore any new updates on it without breaking?

Comment: Can you simply edit the "software's package update script" to remove the `cmake` entry? (Why is an 'upgrade script' necessary on a deb-based system?)

Comment: @user535733 No unfortunately that is out of my control cause it's nested into some other packages that goes down many levels (maybe 10)

Comment: Can you un-hold the package, and downgrade it (and re-hold it) after the script has done it's work?