# How tell apt-get to only update/upgrade a package only if a newer version is available?

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, apt, package-management, upgrade

I am running a script that somehow upgrades packages behind the scene over which I have no control. All I know is that the script uses `apt-get` to upgrade/update packages. The problem is sometimes the packages that are installed through `apt-get` are older versions of the packages that I already have on my machine.

So I wonder, is there a way to enforce `apt-get` to only install a package only if a newer version of that package is available?

I tried using `apt-mark hold packageName` as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1212837/apt-get-does-not-proceed-with-package-installation-if-one-package-is-held) but this does not resolve my issue as that update script throws an error as follow and nothing is done after that point:

> E: Held packages were changed and -y was used without
>   --allow-change-held-packages. ERROR! apt-get failed to install requested packages, exiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your question while searching for a solution for a similar problem and after looking through some docs I found something that might work for you:

```
apt-get -o dpkg::Options::=--refuse-downgrade
```